# AdMobFree not shows ads on Ionic 3 app when isTesting is false

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, admob, ionic3, ionic-native

I am developing an ionic(version: 3.19.0) and cordova(version: 7.1.0) iOS app and using ionic native admob free plugin ( https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-free/ ) to display ads.
The ad shows when isTesting: true but no ads shows when isTesting: false. My ad unit id is correct and ad shows(with the same ad unit ids) correctly when I use AdMob Pro plugin. The ad prepare event calls successfully but no ads. I am stuck and I dont know where the mistake. Below the code I used.

```
 const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
        id:MY_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE,
        isTesting: false,
        autoShow: true
      };
      this.admob.banner.config(bannerConfig);
      this.admob.banner.prepare()
        .then(() => {
//This event calls successfully
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: For that u have to run in production mode.

Comment: Thank you @Husain for reply. I added enableProdMode() but still not showing ad. Below the code i used to enable prod mode. Added at first line of app.module.ts import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
enableProdMode();

Comment: Remove isTesting line and try to release signed apk.

Comment: Hi @Husain I removed IsTesting line. Still no ad. This is iOS version.

Comment: Sorry but I had no idea for ios platform.